# Android how to get/retrieve the data from bundle?

Tags: android, bundle, android-bundle

I'm sending data from one class using this

```
 intent.putExtra("alarmMgr_id", alarm_id);
```

I'm getting the data in the other class in the bundle but I don't know how to retrieve it from the bundle im attaching a screenshot:

[image]

Please guide me how to get this data that has red star at its end;
I want to store these two variables wakelockid=3, alarmMgr_id=9 as integers.

I did already try this but it didn't worked for me so please  see the debug mode screenshot; the alarmManager_id  returns null every time.

```
 Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
 int alarmManager_id = extras.getInt("alarmMgr_id");
```

Consider this as class A that sends the data

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReciever extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
// The app's AlarmManager, which provides access to the system alarm
// services.
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
// The pending intent that is triggered when the alarm fires.
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String alarm_id = intent.getAction();
    Intent service = new Intent(context, AlarmSchedulingService.class);
    service.putExtra("alarmMgr_id", alarm_id);
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, service);
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void setAlarm_RepeatOnce(Context context, int year, int month,
        int date, int hours, int minutes, TaskModel currentTask) {
    try {
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        int alarm_id = currentTask._id;
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmBroadcastReciever.class);
        intent.setAction(String.valueOf(alarm_id));  

        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, alarm_id , intent,  
                  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, date);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);

        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                alarmIntent);

        // Enable {@code AlarmBootBroadCastReceiver} to automatically
        // restart the alarm
        // when the
        // device is rebooted.
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context,
                AlarmBootBroadcastReceiverRepeatOnce.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        String e = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
}
}
```

and this as class B which recieves the data now if you go to the screenshot you can see im getting the data in the bundle but I don't know how to extract it and you can also see in the code the methods I have tried to extract the values but all return null.

```
public class AlarmSchedulingService extends IntentService {
DatabaseHelper db;
Context mContext;
public AlarmSchedulingService() {
    super("SchedulingService");
}

// An ID used to post the notification.
public int NOTIFICATION_ID;//= 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
//Bundle extras;


@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    try{


       // Get passed values
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    int uniqueID = extras.getInt("alarm_id");
    int alarmMgr_id =  extras.getInt("alarmMgr_id");  
    int alarmMgr_idd = extras.getParcelable("alarmMgr_id");



   // NOTIFICATION_ID = alarmMgr_id;//uniqueID;
   // sendNotification(alarmMgr_id);
    // Release the wake lock provided by the BroadcastReceiver.
    AlarmBroadcastReciever.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        String ex = e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
}
// Post a notification
private void sendNotification(  int alarm_id) {
    //code for notificaiton generation
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried to search how to retrieve data from bundle,there are tons of eamples

Comment: yes i did searched but non helped to me because non of the solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way in onCreate of your Activity

```
  int alarmMgr_id;

  if(getIntent().getIntExtra("alarmMgr_id",yourDefaultValue)!=null)
  alarmMgr_id=getIntent().getIntExtra("alarmMgr_id",yourDefaultValue);
```

But after seeing you code, I realised that here in this line of code

```
service.putExtra("alarmMgr_id", alarm_id);
```

you are sending alarm_id which is a String variable and in you service where you are trying to retrieve that like this

```
 int alarmMgr_id =  extras.getInt("alarmMgr_id");
```

i.e you are using getInt(), So just change your this line to this

```
 int alarmMgr_id =  Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("alarmMgr_id"));
```

and this will do the trick.

Comment: Mr. Rana i have already tried this but it was useless.
     Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
     int alarmManager_id = extras.getInt("alarmMgr_id");

Comment: You should have retrieved data using bundles, if you have wrapped your data in bundle while sending through intent. But in your code,you are sending data individually, so you have to retrieve that through getIntent()

Comment: you just show me the whole code while calling next activity intent, then i'll get idea how actually you are sending

Comment: ok let me show the code, wait

Comment: @Rana i have uploaded the code please take a look

Comment: intent.putExtra("alarmMgr_id", alarm_id); In this line, what is the data type of your alarm_id??

Comment: it has to be an integer finally. But i'm sending it as a string for now. I'll parse it to int once i get it

Comment: So that is the problem, actually you are sending String value in putExtra, but looking for int in your extras in service. In your service,use extras.getString("alarmMgr_id");  and before assigning it to your int variable, you should parse it

Comment: i've tried both getString and getInt but let me try it again and will confirm the output in while

Comment: yeah sure, go ahead but i am sure that this was the only problem.

Comment: yes it did worked thanks it was due to getInt

Comment: okay congrats..now let me update my answer.. :)